# Как вернуть QPushButton к обратному состоянию pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть такой код:

```
self.checkBtn = QPushButton('', self)
self.checkBtn.setIcon(QIcon('images/background/CheckBtn passive.png'))
self.checkBtn.setIconSize(QSize(60, 50))
self.checkBtn.clicked[bool].connect(self.setActiveCheck)

def setActiveCheck(self):
        button = self.sender()
        button.setIcon(QIcon('images/background/CheckBtn active.png'))
        button.setIconSize(QSize(60, 50))
```

При нажатии кнопки, у него меняется картинка на фоне. Проблема в том, что нужно обратно `изменять картинку в первоначальное состояние при повторном нажатии`. Функцию скопировал, все изменил, но как это поместить в событие, чтобы подключалось в зависимости от булевой переменной?

Решение найдено, но теперь оно не хочет работать:

```
self.checkBtn = QPushButton('', self)
self.checkBtn.setIcon(QIcon('images/background/CheckBtnpassive.png'))
self.checkBtn.setIconSize(QSize(60, 50))
self.checkBtn.toggled.connect(self.setActive)

def setActive(self, state):
        if state:
            self.checkBtn.setIcon(QIcon('images/background/CheckBtn active.png'))
            self.checkBtn.setIconSize(QSize(60, 50))
        else:
            self.checkBtn.setIcon(QIcon('images/background/CheckBtnpassive.png'))
            self.checkBtn.setIconSize(QSize(60, 50))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю делать так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class AppDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.checkBtn = QPushButton('', self)

        self.checkBtn.setCheckable(True)                                       # +++

        self.checkBtn.setIcon(QIcon('Ok.png'))    # ('images/background/CheckBtn passive.png'))
        self.checkBtn.setIconSize(QSize(60, 50))
#        self.checkBtn.clicked[bool].connect(self.setActiveCheck)
        self.checkBtn.toggled.connect(self.setActiveCheck)                     # +++

    def setActiveCheck(self, state):
        if state:
            self.checkBtn.setIcon(QIcon('im.png'))
        else:
            self.checkBtn.setIcon(QIcon('Ok.png'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)        
    demo = AppDemo()
    demo.resize(200, 100)
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересно, не проще было бы через QSS сделать? :)

Comment: @gil9red  мне думается, что не проще.

Comment: Теперь получается какая-то несуразица. Код ошибок не выдает, но кнопка не реагирует на нажатие. Исправил вопрос, добавил код

Comment: @qwerty  `CheckBtn active.png` что за пробел? Проверьте правильность написание путей к изображениям.

Comment: @S. Nick С путями проблем нету

Comment: @qwerty `CheckBtn active.png`  что за пробел между словами `CheckBtn` и `active.png`?